# How to get the column and max value column

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the System column with the MaxCount using below query

```
SELECT
    MAX(x.MaxCount) AS MostCommon 
FROM
    (SELECT
         SYSTEM, COUNT(*) MaxCount 
     FROM 
         test
     WHERE
         DESCRIPTION = 1 AND DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY
         SYSTEM) x
```

But it returns the `MostCommon` column only.

Comment: what is your db ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database support it, `ROW_NUMBER` is one option here:

```
SELECT SYSTEM, cnt AS MaxCount
FROM
(
    SELECT SYSTEM, COUNT(*) AS cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM test
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = 1
    GROUP BY SYSTEM
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Specific for SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SYSTEM, COUNT(*) AS MaxCount   -- or TOP 1 WITH TIES for all tied systems
FROM test
WHERR DESCRIPTION = 1
GROUP BY SYSTEM
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I think this will be much better: SELECT top 1 SYSTEM, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM test
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = 1
    GROUP BY SYSTEM
 order by cnt

Comment: @Sabbu Of course, if you're using SQL Server then `TOP` is another option.